# error on inserting into table

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to insert data into a table with this code:

```
try
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "connection_string";
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE UXZona(IDZona int,Morada char(50));", conn))
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UXZona(FirstColumn, SecondColumn) VALUES (@0, @1)", conn);

}
catch (Exception)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("create table UXZona(IDZona int NOT NULL, Morada varchar(50) NOT NULL);", conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Tabela criada com sucesso");
}
```

I launch the program without any problem, but it stops the debug and gives me this error message:

> "There is already an object named 'UXZona' in the database"

It skips the `try{}` and goes directly to the `catch{}`. Any clue on what I'm doing wrong? Feel free to ask for more code if needed.

Comment: Your connection string is wrong

Comment: It doesn't *skip* the try block, it executes it up until the command that attempts to create a table throws an exception, **then** it "skips" to the catch block. If this is not what you intended to do, why did you write the code like this? You should probably only create the table if it does not already exist.

Comment: Creating tables should be done at design time, not at run time. That's your first mistake.

Comment: You are repeating your errors of yesterday, just in a new question.  Your insertCommand does nothing.  You put code into the catch that belongs elsewhere, and in your catch, you don't report what the Exception is (use Message Box for example).   Please read the answer I gave you yesterday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE UXZona(IDZona int,Morada char(50));", conn)
```

You should check if object already exists:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('UXZona', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE UXZona(IDZona int,Morada char(50));", conn)
```

I would also rethink your approach of creating DB object during runtime. It requires DDL priviliges and could lead to problems with security.

Comment: OBJECT_ID is an SQL-function, it Returns the database object identification number of a schema-scoped object.